# Use a Checkbox to filter list box to max value of field

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm attempting to setup a simple checkbox where, when clicked true, it will filter a list box to the max value of the field.

I setup the checkbox in the form with the listbox and used the following code for after update.

```
Private Sub CheckBurst_AfterUpdate()
If CheckBurst = True Then
   Me.SBoutputlst = "MAX([SBoutputlst]![Burst DPS])'"
   Me.FilterOn = True
Else
  Me.FilterOn = False
End If
Me.Requery
Me.SBoutputlst.Requery
End Sub
```

The problem is it doesn't seem to be filtering. I'm not sure what I've gotten wrong.
The Listbox is named `SBoutputlst` the field I want the max value for in that list is `Burst DPS`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
Adding SQL version of the query for my listbox

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
ShipWeaponHPtbl.Ship, 
ShipWeaponHPtbl.[Hardpoint Size], 
ShipWeaponHPtbl.[Number of Hard Points], 
Weapons.Weapon, 
Weapons.Type, 
Weapons.Ammo, 
Weapons.[Burst DPS] AS [Default Burst DPS], 
[Weapons]![Burst DPS]*[ShipWeaponHPtbl]![Number of Hard Points] AS [Burst DPS], 
Weapons.[Alpha DPS] AS [Default Alpha DPS], 
[Weapons]![Alpha DPS]*[ShipWeaponHPtbl]![Number of Hard Points] AS [Alpha DPS], 
Weapons.[Full Load Dmg], 
Weapons.[Full Load Dmg In], Weapons.[Fire Rate], 
Weapons.Speed, Weapons.Range, 
Weapons.HP, Ships.[Capacitor Pilot],
 Ships.[Capacitor Turret 1], 
Ships.[Capacitor Turret 2], 
Ships.[Capacitor Turret 3], 
ComponentLoc.[Location 1], 
ComponentLoc.[Location 1 Cost], 
ComponentLoc.[Location 2], 
ComponentLoc.[Location 2 Cost], 
ComponentLoc.[Location 3], 
ComponentLoc.[Location 3 Cost], 
Ships.[Ship Image], 
Ships.[Cargo Size], 
Ships.[EM Signature], 
Ships.[IR Signature]
FROM ((ShipWeaponHPtbl INNER JOIN Weapons ON ShipWeaponHPtbl.[Hardpoint Size] = Weapons.[Hard Point Size]) 
INNER JOIN Ships ON ShipWeaponHPtbl.Ship = Ships.[Ship Name]) 
INNER JOIN ComponentLoc ON Weapons.Weapon = ComponentLoc.Component
WHERE (((ShipWeaponHPtbl.Ship) Like "*" & [forms]![ShipBuilder]![Shiptxt] & "*") 
AND ((Weapons.Type) Like "*" & [forms]![ShipBuilder]![WeaponTypetxt] & "*"))
ORDER BY ShipWeaponHPtbl.Ship;
```

That is the main query. the one specifically use for the list box is :

```
SELECT PotentialDPSqry.Ship, PotentialDPSqry.[Hardpoint Size], PotentialDPSqry.[Number of Hard Points], PotentialDPSqry.Weapon, PotentialDPSqry.Type, PotentialDPSqry.Ammo, PotentialDPSqry.[Burst DPS], PotentialDPSqry.[Alpha DPS], PotentialDPSqry.[Full Load Dmg], PotentialDPSqry.[Full Load Dmg In], PotentialDPSqry.[Fire Rate], PotentialDPSqry.Speed, PotentialDPSqry.Range, PotentialDPSqry.HP, PotentialDPSqry.[Location 1], PotentialDPSqry.[Location 1 Cost]
FROM PotentialDPSqry;
```

Comment: `FilterOn` activates the property `Filter` of `Me` (the _form_ itself) ... completely unrelated to a listbox. So ...

Comment: @hansup No I’m actually trying to filter it so only the max value is shown is the list box.

Comment: @HansUp the list box is based on a query. I’ve removed the filter property. But trying to figure out what is wrong with my syntax cause while it doesn’t throw an error it isn’t filtering either.

Comment: The SQL view of my query is pretty big so I'll edit and show it in my OP

Comment: If your query can include multiple rows which match the max `[Burst DPS]`, save that SQL as a named query and use it as the list box rowsource.  Then, in `CheckBurst_AfterUpdate`, you can change the rowsource to a new SELECT which adds a constraint to the named query: `SELECT * FROM [YourNamedQuery] WHERE [Burst DPS] = DMax('[Burst DPS]', 'YourNamedQuery')`